# Change the title on Module-Newsletter

Tags: magento2, module, layout, xml

Ok, this sounds like it should be really simple but its driving me crazy. All I want to do is change the title above the Newsletter subscribe form in the footer of **Magento 2**. I have a child theme of Luma.

I thought I could just copy module-newsletter from `vendor/magento/module-newsletter` in to my theme directory and it would override. But this doesn't seem to be the case. There must be a way of altering the `/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/templates/subscribe.phtml` file from my child theme?

Answer (score 1):

at your theme directory and the file path

```
 design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe.phtml
```

> Vendor: the first char Uppercase
>
> themename: lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Create a module and rewrite subscribe class

**app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" type="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Subscribe"/>  
</config>
```

Block file **app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Block/Subscribe.php**  as below

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;


class Subscribe extends Template
{

    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function beforeToHtml(\Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe $originalBlock)
    {
        $originalBlock->setTemplate('Namespace_Modulename::subscribe.phtml');
    }    

}
```

your phtml file **app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/subscribe.phtml**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create any custom module for overriding phtml file. All you need to do is override the file in your theme at this location

> app/design/frontend/[VENDOR NAME]/[THEME NAME]/Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe.phtml